# Spring Caching - How to manage caches in different scopes?

Tags: java, spring, caching, scope, ehcache

I'm working on a Spring MVC application using Spring Caching Abstraction. The cache implementation is EhCache in version 2.6.5

Now I need two caches - one application scoped and another session scoped, since some method results are based on the web session. What is the best way to achieve this?

I figured that I can't register the session cache in the same CacheManager as the global cache, since there might be no session available when spring tries to inject the CacheManager. Therefore I have another CacheManager which is session scoped...

```
@Bean
public net.sf.ehcache.Cache sessionCache() {
    return new net.sf.ehcache.Cache(sessionCacheConfiguration());
}

@Bean
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public CacheManager sessionCacheManager(){
    net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager sessionCacheManager = net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create();
    sessionCacheManager.setName("sessionCacheManager");
    sessionCacheManager.addCache(sessionCache());

    return new EhCacheCacheManager(sessionCacheManager);
}

@Bean
public CacheManager globalCacheManager() {
    return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheCacheManager().getObject());
}

@Bean
public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheCacheManager() {
    EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cmfb = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    cmfb.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
    cmfb.setShared(true);
    return cmfb;
}

@Bean
public CompositeCacheManager cacheManager(){
    return new CompositeCacheManager(globalCacheManager(), sessionCacheManager()){{
        setFallbackToNoOpCache(true);
    }};
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work properly, spring creates the sessionCacheManager only once. So I get the cached results over all sessions.

Comment: Can you add information on where you use these caches and cache managers? I believe your CompositeCacheManager is causing you trouble.

Comment: I use `@Cacheable("sessionCache")` and `@Cacheable("globalCache")` on my service methods. The CompositeCacheManager works like a charm, it's able to handle multiple CacheManagers...

Answer (score 1):

You can only store serializable beans in a session. Of course, as long as you only have a single application node, you can technically store everything by the object reference. However, it will not be available after restart.

If you want to cache data belonging to a session define a global cache with a compound key (session-id, you-key).

Comment: It's not my goal to serialize the session cache...

I'd prefer having several caches for different purposes. Since the cache configuration varies significantly! e.g. eternal, not eternal